# Custom 404 error issues with Apache - the ErrorDocument is 404 as well

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I am trying to create a custom 404 error for my website. I am testing this out using XAMPP on Windows.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
error\404page.html
index.php
.htaccess
```

The content of my .htaccess file is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 error\404page.html
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

However this is not working - is it something to do with the way the slashes are or how I should be referencing the error document?

site site documents reside in a in a sub folder of the web root if that makes any difference to how I should reference?

When I change the file to be

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404page.html
```

I receive the following error message which isn't what is inside the html file I have linked - but it is different to what is listed above:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the slash to a forward slash? Not sure if Apache supports backslashes.

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 /error/404page.html

is what it now is and this throws a 404 exception - however this isn't the exception that is in the html file that I have linked.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive, when supplied a local URL path, expects the path to be fully qualified from the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot). In your case, this means that the actual path to the `ErrorDocument` is

```
ErrorDocument 404 /JinPortfolio/error/404page.html
```

When you corrected it in your second try, the reason you see that page instead is because `http://localhost/error/404page.html` doesn't exist, hence the bit about there being a 404 error in locating the error handling document.

Comment: Just declare it in htaccess? I'v got Server error message!

Answer (score 11):

.htaccess files are disabled by default in Apache these days, due to performance issues. When .htaccess files are enabled, the web server must check for it on every hit in every subdirectory from where it resides.

Just figured it was important to note. If you want to turn on .htaccess files anyway, here's a link that explains it:

http://www.tildemark.com/enable-htaccess-on-apache/

Answer (score 6):

Instead of adding them to your .htaccess file, you can add them to any of your virtual host files.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ErrorDocument 404 /error-pages/404.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /error-pages/500.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /error-pages/503.html
    ErrorDocument 504 /error-pages/504.html

</VirtualHost>
```

Where `error-pages` is a subfolder in the `mywebsite` folder, containing the custom error pages. Make sure you restart your apache to view your changes.

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever url you enter as the default 404 page must be either absolute or relative from the root folder : That's why some make the mistake of treating its url like the rewrite engines' url which is relative from the folder where .htaccess is located.