# Custom 404 Error Page in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am a novice in PHP, I hope you can help me with this problem.
How can I create a custom 404 error page in PHP without going anywhere or redirect it to other page.

Ex. `mysite.com/no-where`

The page `no-where` does not exists. I want to display a 404 error message with design on that URL.

How can I get the current URL? I got an error on this. Coz I want to check the header if its 404.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$array = get_headers($url);
$string = $array[0];
if(strpos($string,"200")) {
    echo 'url exists';
} else {
    echo 'url does not exist';
}
```

Comment: Create a `404.php` page or `404.htm` file with whatever style you wish, and in `.htaccess` do `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`, no? Or is that considered too "Old Skool"?

Comment: no, I don't want to redirect user to other page. I want to display error message exactly at the url he/she is browsing currently.

Comment: Ok, well see Wayne's answer then.

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` doesn't change your original URL. It will remain at `mysite.com/no-where` in the browser.

Comment: when i tried it i got an error `The requested URL /no-where was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: thanks! I already found the error!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file and put the following line in it:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpageFileName.php
```

That will set the page 'errorpageFileName.php to your error 404 page. You can of course change the file name to your likings.

You can read more in-depth about it here:
[Custom 404 error issues with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397868/custom-404-error-htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

It's really important to have a correct 404 error page, because:

- It helps your site / webapp visitors to guide for the correct place in your site
- Much better SEO
- It's just looks better

In additional the the answers here, I would suggest you to have different messages for different error types. For example, define in your `.htacess` file an error page for different failure types:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

More information about [custom 404 error pages](https://www.copahost.com/blog/create-custom-404-error-page-htaccess/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache as a web server you can create a file named `.htaccess` in the root directory of your website. This can contain various rules, including error handling, as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 404 (Your site error 404 page URL)
```

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.domain/custom-404-page.html
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line in .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Page not found."
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a 404 header and then require your 404 template / page.

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
include '404.php';
exit;
```

That or you can [configure Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) to serve up a custom page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache as a web server and cpanel, just click menu error page, choose 404 error not found and edit the editor with your custom html page and save. You will get automatic file 404.shtml in your folder.

If you are using vps openlitespeed and webadmin panel, there is error not found and fill with your custom 404 html page.

If your panel is cyberpanel at openlitespeed, just create your custom 404 html page (ex:404.html), then edit your vHost Conf and fill with line:

```
errorpage 404 {
  url                     /404.html
}
```

And save it